# how can i get data from method return value

Tags: kotlin

i use kotlin
i want to get data from method

```
fun Example() : String{

 var value : String

     client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                print("Getting Data Failed")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                value = "aaa"
            }  
     }

 return value
}
```

finally i want to get value..
but Callback function works late
how can i get value data("aaa")

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your question, you want to perform the request synchronously.  This can be done with code like:

```
fun Example(): String {
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    val value = if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        "aaa"
    } else {
        error("request failed")
    }
    return value
}
```